# Opening Windows 10 Subsystem for Linux takes me to "/windows/System32"?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

When I run wsl from windows powershell, it takes me to /mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32 . Apparently, it is supposed to be my username-- how do I change this?

EDIT: the start pathway is set to my home pathway. It seems to only be doing this when I run as an administrator;

Comment: What is the exact start pathway you have configured?

Answer (score 0):

The `wsl` command is picking up the current working directory of the Powershell. So you just need to `cd` to wherever you want to be either before or after launching WSL from within Powershell.

On my PC, "Windows Powershell (Admin)" sets the default working directory to `C:\WINDOWS\system32` so wsl uses `/mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32`. The non-admin "Windows Powershell" starts in my current directory `C:\Users\SOMEUSERID`, and therefore WSL starts in `/mnt/c/Users/SOMEUSERID`. This is not same as the Linux user accounts home - try `cd ~` which should be `/home/linuxuserid`.

Note that Powershell as Admin user may not have access to the Network mount points of your normal user account so if your home directory is mapped to a network drive then the Powershell (Admin) and WSL might not see your Windows user home.